# Error in c# subtracting 30 days from current date ? winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I need to subtract 30 days from current date then i filter query but i didn't get any results/ output why whats my error on this code

```
DateTime curdate = DateTime.Now;
curdate = curdate.AddDays(-30); // if i give -4 instead of -30 the query will bind data
DateTime curdate1 = DateTime.Now;

validateDept.InitializeConnection();
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(validateDept.connetionString);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceId, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, (Select CustomerId from Customer Where Customer.CustomerId=NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerId, (Select CustomerName from Customer where Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerName, DueDate, Tax, GrandTotal, CompanyId FROM NewInvoice_1 WHERE InvoiceDate >= '" + curdate + "' AND InvoiceDate <= '" + curdate1 + "' ", connection);
DataSet sourceDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(sourceDataSet);
gridControl1.DataSource = sourceDataSet.Tables[0];
```

empty table only shows if i run this code. If i change -30 to -4 then it fetch one row from Access DB. From 1st april to current date 8th april if we give -3,-4,-5,-6, -7 this code but works small error is that "<" & ">" this only working "=" sign not working in this code ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: work with parameters the error is because you are converting it to a string and it depends of the format of the date... and the format in your server, also read about sql injection, so you are not passing a date, you are passing an stng that is why is not working

Comment: In addition to @Mr. - see [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) for examples.

Comment: @Mr. - it would be hard to do SQL injection given that the parameter is a date - but still agree that parameters are the right thing to do here

Comment: @greg i know that, it's just for his own good to search why he should not use inline parameters or querys in that way, As the twig is bent, so grows the tree

Comment: Hi @Mr, Thanks for commenting ya am passing a string(date). How to pass date directly ? How to solve this ?

Comment: @Sri - on the linked page for [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx), you will find examples on how exactly you would use them. Just tell the parameter, what type it should be (in your case "DateTime" or similar) and put the value in the `Value` property of the parameter.

Comment: NOT the right way to do it, but you could cast the date to a string in the format of dd MMM yyyy and that would fix your problem. But don't do it that way, use parameters as everyone else has suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using access as database then use # not ''
one more thing pass date string with full month name this will ignore local date settings

```
DateTime curdate = DateTime.Now;
curdate = curdate.AddDays(-30); // if i give -4 instead of -30 the query will bind data
DateTime curdate1 = DateTime.Now;

validateDept.InitializeConnection();
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(validateDept.connetionString);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(
      "SELECT InvoiceId, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, (Select CustomerId from Customer
      Where Customer.CustomerId=NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerId, (Select
      CustomerName from Customer where Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName)
      AS CustomerName, DueDate, Tax, GrandTotal, CompanyId FROM NewInvoice_1 WHERE
      InvoiceDate >= #" + curdate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "# AND InvoiceDate <= #" +         
      curdate1.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "# ", connection);

DataSet sourceDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(sourceDataSet);
gridControl1.DataSource = sourceDataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Hi @jack, Thanks for answering but Still facing same problem :(